# Postgres time with time zone equality

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, timezone

I'm having some trouble with `time with time zone` equalities in Postgres.  `timestamp with time zone` equality works how I would expect it to, where if the times are the same after normalizing the timezones, it should be true:

```
postgres=# select '2013-06-27 12:00:00 -0800'::timestamp with time zone = '2013-06-27 14:00:00 -0600'::timestamp with time zone;
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

However, the same does not seem to apply to `time with time zone`:

```
postgres=# select '12:00:00 -0800'::time with time zone = '14:00:00 -0600'::time with time zone;
 ?column?
----------
 f
```

Yet inequalities work how I would expect them to:

```
postgres=# select '12:00:00 -0800'::time with time zone < '14:01:00 -0600'::time with time zone;
 ?column?
----------
 t

postgres=# select '12:00:00 -0800'::time with time zone > '13:59:00 -0600'::time with time zone;
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about `time with time zone`?  How can I evaluate for equality in a way that handles time zones the same way `timestamp with time zone` equality does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways to evaluate `timetz` equality:

```sql
SELECT a, b, a = b AS plain_equality
     , '2000-1-1'::date + a = '2000-1-1'::date + b AS ts_equality
     , a AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', b AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS timetz_equality
FROM  (
   SELECT '12:00:00 -0800'::timetz AS a
        , '14:00:00 -0600'::timetz AS b
   ) sub;
```

The first by adding it to a `date`.
The second by using the [`AT TIME ZONE` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).

But rather don't use `time with time zone` at all.
Postgres supports the type only because it is in the SQL standard. It is broken by design (cannot consider DST!) and its use is discouraged.

Quoting the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the
> definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.
> In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without time zone`, and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete range of
> date/time functionality required by any application.

Comment: Ok, we should not use `time with time zone`, but how we should save a hour of day that is locale dependent? Should we use the `time` column and transform to UTC in the application layer or it is better indicated to combine, if available, the date with the time and use a `timestamp with time zone` column even if we already have a column for the date in the same table? What approach do you recommend?

Comment: @Luiz: It depends on the information you actually *need*. Abstract time? Absolute point in time? Time and place? Or time and time zone? Please present your case as new *question*, comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context. And drop a comment here if you want to link back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created a new question as you suggested. If you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277141/properly-handle-time-with-time-zone-in-postgresql