# Get difference in minutes between times with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
(
    time_A time with timezone
);
```

How to get the difference in minutes between `now()` and `time_A`?

Comment: now() yields a timestamp, not a time, you need to be more specific how to deal with times before / after the stored time ...

Comment: I want get diff between current time with current time zone and another time with timezone in table

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The type `timetz` is **broken by the design** and its use is discouraged:

- [Postgres time with time zone equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529284/postgres-time-with-time-zone-equality/20530283#20530283)

To factor in the time zone, use `timestamptz` instead. But be aware that the actual time zone is not stored explicitly:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-data-type-timestamp-with-time-zone/28876266#28876266)

Details for timestamp / time zone handling in Postgres:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

#### Solution

Assuming `time` instead.

```
SELECT EXTRACT('epoch' FROM now()::time - time_a) / 60 AS minutes
FROM   tablea;
```

`now()` returns `timestamptz`, which is adjusted for the current time zone automatically. You get the local time when casting to `time`. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

Subtracting two times yields an `interval` (which can be negative, of course).

Apply [`EXTRACT('epoch' FROM ...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to get the number of seconds in that interval. Divide by 60. Integer division truncates fractions.