# Extract date from datetime and calculate total minutes from duration

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a table in Postgres as follows:

```
| id | start_time               | end_time                 | duration |
|----|--------------------------|--------------------------|----------|
| 1  | 2018-05-11T00:00:20.631Z | 2018-05-11T01:03:14.496Z | 1:02:54  |
| 2  | 2018-05-11T00:00:04.877Z | 2018-05-11T00:00:14.641Z | 0:00:10  |
| 3  | 2018-05-11T01:03:28.063Z | 2018-05-11T01:04:36.410Z | 0:01:08  |
| 4  | 2018-05-11T00:00:20.631Z | 2018-05-11T02:03:14.496Z | 2:02:54  |
```

`start_time` and `end_time` are stored as `varchar`. Format is `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ms'` (ISO format).
`duration` has been calculated as `end_time - start_time`. Format is `hh:mi:ss`.

I need result table output as follows:

```
| id | start_time               | end_time                 | duration | start     | end       | duration_minutes |
|----|--------------------------|--------------------------|----------|-----------|-----------|------------------|
| 1  | 2018-05-11T00:00:20.631Z | 2018-05-11T01:03:14.496Z | 1:02:54  | 5/11/2018 | 5/11/2018 | 62               | -- (60+2)
| 2  | 2018-05-11T00:00:04.877Z | 2018-05-11T00:00:14.641Z | 0:00:10  | 5/11/2018 | 5/11/2018 | 0                |
| 3  | 2018-05-11T01:03:28.063Z | 2018-05-11T01:04:36.410Z | 0:01:08  | 5/11/2018 | 5/11/2018 | 1                |
| 4  | 2018-05-11T00:00:20.631Z | 2018-05-11T02:03:14.496Z | 2:02:54  | 5/11/2018 | 5/11/2018 | 122              | -- (2X60 +2)
```

`start` and `end` need to contain only the `mm/dd/yyyy` portion of `start_time` and `end_time` respectively.

`duration_minutes` should calculate total duration in minutes (eg, if duration is 1:02:54, duration in minutes should be 62 which is 60+2)

How can I do this using SQL?

Comment: Use the appropriate data type. `varchar` isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing timestamps as varchar? That's a really bad idea

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : I will store it as datetime

Comment: There is no `datetime` in Postgres. `timestamp` or `timestamptz`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860. And `duration` should probably be type `interval`. Shall we keep assuming `varchar` input or `timestamp` / `interval`? And do you need the `T` and `Z` decorators in your result? Those are optional in ISO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in `varchar` input, this query produces your desired result, exactly:

```sql
SELECT *
     , to_char(start_time::timestamp, 'FMMM/DD/YYYY') AS start
     , to_char(end_time::timestamp  , 'FMMM/DD/YYYY') AS end
     , extract(epoch FROM duration::interval)::int / 60 AS duration_minutes
FROM   tbl;
```

**Major points:**

- Use `timestamp` and `interval` instead of `varchar` to begin with.
  Or do not *store* the functionally dependent column `duration` at all. It can cheaply be computed on the fly.
- For *display* / a *particular text representation* use [**`to_char()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE).
  Be explicit and do not rely on locale settings that may change from session to session.
  The `FM` pattern modifier is for ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE)):

  > fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)
- `extract (epoch FROM interval_tpe)` produces the number of contained seconds. You want to truncate fractional minutes? Integer division does just that, so cast to `int` like demonstrated. Related:

  - [Get difference in minutes between times with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300460/get-difference-in-minutes-between-times-with-timezone/23300611#23300611)

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter : I used `extract(epoch FROM duration::interval)::int AS duration_seconds` and  got seconds. But how can I capture the fraction milliseconds

Comment: @Symphony: The cast to integer *rounds* fractional seconds. Drop the cast to get a `double precision` number with up to 6 fractional digits: `extract(epoch FROM duration::interval) AS seconds_with_fractions`. But your duration in the example is rounded already, so you need to recalculate duration to get fractional units. See: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5c645066246021738550de0866819ea0)*

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to do what you want:

```
select v.starttime::timestamp::date, v.endtime::date,
       extract(epoch from v.endtime::timestamp - v.starttime::timestamp)/60
from (values ('2018-05-11T00:00:20.631Z', '2018-05-11T01:03:14.496Z')) v(starttime, endtime)
```

If you want the dates in a particular format, then use `to_char()`.

Comment: I do not want to re-calculate duration. I just want to convert it to minutes