# How can I store only time with timezone in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to store only time with timezone in Sequelize ORM using "postgres" dialect

Comment: `time with timezone` is pretty much useless. Is that really what you are saving or are you using a `timestamp`?

Comment: Just do it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I am using Sequelize ORM, and I did not found any type to store only time with timezone.

Comment: There are Sequelize data types - https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html

Comment: Yes I need to store only time with timezone.

Comment: Don't use `time with time zone` (`timetz`). It's broken by design and officially discouraged. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23300611/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend DATE or TIME DataType of Sequelize like [this](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/other-topics/extending-data-types/) and declare your custom type or just put in the raw datatype like [this](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/other-topics/other-data-types/)