# time with time zone query not behaving has expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, timezone, postgresql-9.1

I have a `time with time zone` column, but when the timezones are different the query does not behave has expected.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE timezone_table (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "time" time with time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT timezone_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here the insert statement to populate:

```
insert into timezone_table (id, created_at, updated_at, "time")
values (1, now(), now(), '12:00:00 UTC');
```

The troublesome query (doesn't find the record as expected):

```
SELECT * FROM "timezone_table" WHERE "timezone_table"."time" = '08:00:00 -0400';
```

A query that works as expected (finds the record):

```
SELECT * FROM "timezone_table" WHERE "timezone_table"."time" = '12:00:00 -0000';
```

So **the question** is, why would the troublesome query not return the row as expected when `08:00:00 -0400` is equivalent to `12:00:00 UTC` (or at least I would expect it to be equivalent)?

The weird part is if the troublesome query uses a less-than operator, it finds the row no problem:

```
SELECT * FROM "timezone_table" WHERE "timezone_table"."time" < '08:00:00 -0400';
```

Comment: The SQL standard seems to do some very weird stuff with time zone comparisons.  I don't remember the details now, but it is along the lines of 'times are stored in UTC and effectively compared in UTC, except that the time zone offset is still relevant for equality comparison'.

Comment: `time with time zone` is frankly awful, and should be avoided. The PostgreSQL documentation even says as much. Use a `timestamptz` where possible; where not, store a `time` and an offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, as mentioned in the comments, that [`timetz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) is **broken by design**. Don't use it. Postgres advises against it, [per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html)

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the
>   definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.
>   In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without time
>   zone`, and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete range of
>   date/time functionality required by any application.

Most importantly, it completely breaks with DST (daylight saving time).
<sup>It's up for debate which concept is more more thoroughly *broken*, DST or `timetz`.</sup>

I suggest `timestamptz` instead. Just cast to retrieve the `time` component (according to the local time zone): `ts_value::time`.

While stuck with your design, use the [`AT TIME ZONE` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) to make the query "work":

```
SELECT * FROM timezone_table
WHERE "time" = '08:00:00 -0400'::timetz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Or, to make it work universally (more or less - remember, the concept is broken):

```
SELECT * FROM timezone_table
WHERE "time" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' = '08:00:00 -0400'::timetz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

This little demo should help to explain:

```
SELECT t1, t2
      ,t1 = t2 AS test_fail
      ,t1 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' = t2 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS test_ok
FROM ( SELECT '12:00:00 UTC'::timetz   AS t1
             ,'08:00:00 -0400'::timetz AS t2) sub;
```

Related answer:

- [Postgres time with time zone equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529284/postgres-time-with-time-zone-equality/20530283#20530283)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I read the documentation, saw the warnings and was mitigating the problems that it mentioned before the query was constructed -- I just didn't expect the conditional operators to be broken in such an unexpected way. It would almost be better if ``time with time zone`` was undocumented or a clearer warning was issued.