# Comparing TIME WITH TIME ZONE returns unexpected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause

Why does this query return `false`? Is it because of the `22:51:13.202248 +01:00` format?

```
SELECT now()::time at TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'; -- 22:51:13.202248 +01:00

SELECT now()::time at time zone 'Europe/London' > '22:00:00'::time
   AND now()::time < '23:35:00'::time as is_currently_open; -- false
```

Comment: [Don't use time with time zone](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
now()::time at time zone 'Europe/London'
```

... returns a value of `time with time zone` (`timetz`):

Then you compare it to `time [without time zone]`. Don't do this. The `time` value is coerced to `timetz` in the process and a time offset is appended according to the current `timezone` setting. Meaning, your expression will evaluate differently with different settings. What's more, DST rules are not applied properly. **You want none of this!** See:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=840476fa5bc436184bf56cfcc9eb4ae8)*

More generally, [don't use](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz) <strike>`time with time zone` (`timetz`)</strike> at all. The type is broken by design and officially discouraged in Postgres. See:

- [Postgres time with time zone equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529284/postgres-time-with-time-zone-equality/20530283#20530283)

Use instead:

```sql
SELECT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')::time > '22:00:00'
   AND (now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')::time < '23:35:00' AS is_currently_open;
```

The right operand can be an untyped literal now, it will be coerced to `time` as it should.

`BETWEEN` is often the wrong tool for times and timestamps. See:

- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267877/3684)

But it would seem that `>=` and `<=` are more appropriate for ***opening hours***? Then `BETWEEN` fits the use case and makes it a bit simpler:

```
SELECT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')::time
       BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:35:00' AS is_currently_open;
```

Related:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation! I fixed my issue! It was part of more complex query but your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: @Anita: For an "hours of operation" query, the added link might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to adapt the timezone on the second predicate to get the result you want:

```
SELECT 
        now()::time at time zone 'Europe/London' > '22:00:00'::time 
    AND now()::time at time zone 'Europe/London' < '23:35:00'::time 
    ----------------^----------------> here
AS is_currently_open;
```

Comment: This fixes an obvious omission, but not the broken design. The expression is a loaded footgun, nobody should use it.