# Why the date of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is different from CURRENT_DATE in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The current time in Shanghai is 2024-03-19 00:43

```sql
show timezone
+----------+
| TimeZone |
|----------|
| GMT      |
+----------+

SELECT CURRENT_DATE  AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai', CURRENT_TIME  AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai';
 
+---------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| timezone            | timezone              | timezone                  |
|---------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------|
| 2024-03-18 08:00:00 | 00:43:52.916370+08:00 | 2024-03-19 00:43:52.91637 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

1. Why the date of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is different from CURRENT_DATE in Postgres?
2. How can I get the current date in Shanghai for the result '2024-03-19' if the time zone is GMT?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is just the date (ie at midnight) in the current time zone. See the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: 1) Add the returned value of `show timezone` as text update to question. 2) A date does not have a time zone. When you use `AT TIME ZONE` you are turning it into a timestamp based at Midnight of whatever the `timezone` is set to. This is not the same as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which is the timestamp at that moment in time. 3) `CURRENT_TIME  AT TIME ZONE` is not really meaningful.

Comment: How can I get the current date in Shanghai for the result '2024-03-19'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The similar sounding expressions [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) and [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) are very different in nature.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns data type `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`), and does not depend on local settings. (Only the *display* does, but it's always the same point in time with a different offset.) When you apply the [`AT TIME ZONE` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) you produce the corresponding local `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`) for the given time zone. Still the same point in universal time.

`CURRENT_DATE` returns data type `date`, and depends on the current `timezone` setting of the session. It's the local timestamp **truncated** to the date. This truncation introduces the difference, the quantity depends on the current `timezone` setting. When applying the `AT TIME ZONE` construct, `date` is coerced back to `timestamp` with time component `00:00` (materializing the difference accrued by truncating earlier) before generating the `timestamptz` for the given time zone. It's now a different point in universal time!

And `CURRENT_TIME` returns the questionable type `timetz` (`time with time zone`). This function, as well as the data type are included in the SQL standard, but discouraged in Postgres (or generally, really). The concept of just time with time zone is inherently ambiguous. Think of daylight saving time or historical shifts. I never use `timetz`. (So also not `CURRENT_TIME`.)

Related:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)
- [Get difference in minutes between times with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300460/get-difference-in-minutes-between-times-with-timezone/23300611#23300611)
- [Postgres time with time zone equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529284/postgres-time-with-time-zone-equality/20530283#20530283)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

> If the current `timestamp` in Shanghai is `'2024-03-19 01:29'`, what is the according date? I just need to get `'2024-03-19'`.

Consider the demo:

```sql
SELECT -- current date of the given timestamp (we only know from context that it applies to Shanghai!)
       (timestamp '2024-03-19 01:29')::date
       -- date in Shanghai for a given time in London
     , (timestamp '2024-03-19 01:29' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai')::date
       -- date in London for a given time in Shanghai
     , (timestamp '2024-03-19 01:29' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')::date
       -- date in Shanghai for the given point in time (timestamptz)
     , (timestamptz '2024-03-18 18:29:00+01' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai')::date
       -- date in London for the given point in time (timestamptz)
     , (timestamptz '2024-03-18 19:29:00+02' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')::date
;
```

| d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-19 | 2024-03-19 | 2024-03-18 | 2024-03-19 | 2024-03-18 |

Note how `'2024-03-18 18:29:00+01'` and `'2024-03-18 19:29:00+02'` are just two different text representations for the same point in time (timestamp 1h later, time offset 1h bigger).

Comment: How can I get the current date in Shanghai for the result '2024-03-19' if the time zone is GMT?

Comment: For example, now in shanghai is 2024-03-19 01:29, I just need to get '2024-03-19'

Comment: I added some examples to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the current date in Shanghai for the result '2024-03-19' if the time zone is GMT?

[As already established](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181948/5298879), `date` type doesn't support time zones. If you cast it to `timestamp` which *does* support time zones, you'll get midnight on that date. Switching between these is sufficient for points in time.

But if you want *true dates*, you might be interested in [`timestamptz`-based range type `tstzrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html). It can describe the actual period between two points in time that makes up a specific date. Equipped with that, you can see from GMT what Shanghai would consider the same date:

```
with example(date_as_tsrange) as (values 
  ('[2024-03-19 00:00,
     2024-03-20 00:00)'::tsrange) )
select tsrange(lower(date_as_tsrange) at time zone 'GMT' at time zone 'Asia/Shanghai',
               upper(date_as_tsrange) at time zone 'GMT' at time zone 'Asia/Shanghai')
from example;
```

|  |
| --- |
| ["2024-03-19 08:00:00","2024-03-20 08:00:00") |

To see if `A` happened on the same date as `B`, extracting the date part from each of these would get you the wrong answer; local dates are shifted compared to each other. Meanwhile, the `tstzrange` is specific and absolute, and [`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) tells you if the point is in the range: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-wSqjlLs)

| event_A | event_A_timezone | event_B | event_B_timezone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-19 07:59:00 | GMT | 2024-03-19 06:13:00 | Asia/Shanghai |
| 2024-03-19 00:59:00 | GMT | 2024-03-19 22:13:00 | Asia/Shanghai |
| 2024-03-19 06:47:00 | GMT | 2024-03-19 10:40:00 | Asia/Shanghai |

```sql
with test_with_dates_and_tz as (
  select *,event_a at time zone event_a_timezone as event_a_tz
          ,event_b at time zone event_b_timezone as event_b_tz
          ,tstzrange( (event_a::date  )::timestamp at time zone event_a_timezone
                     ,(event_a::date+1)::timestamp at time zone event_a_timezone) 
           as event_a_date
  from test)
select event_b_tz <@ event_a_date as "did B happen on A's perceived date", *
from test_with_dates_and_tz;
```

| did B happen on A's perceived date | event_a | event_a_timezone | event_b | event_b_timezone | event_a_tz | event_b_tz | event_a_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | 2024-03-19 07:59:00 | GMT | 2024-03-19 06:13:00 | Asia/Shanghai | 2024-03-19 07:59:00+00 | 2024-03-18 22:13:00+00 | ["2024-03-19 00:00:00+00","2024-03-20 00:00:00+00") |
| True | 2024-03-19 00:59:00 | GMT | 2024-03-19 22:13:00 | Asia/Shanghai | 2024-03-19 00:59:00+00 | 2024-03-19 14:13:00+00 | ["2024-03-19 00:00:00+00","2024-03-20 00:00:00+00") |
| True | 2024-03-19 06:47:00 | GMT | 2024-03-19 10:40:00 | Asia/Shanghai | 2024-03-19 06:47:00+00 | 2024-03-19 02:40:00+00 | ["2024-03-19 00:00:00+00","2024-03-20 00:00:00+00") |

Note how the range excludes the upper bound with `)`: it spans up to the midnight of the following date, but doesn't include it. It's more elegant than making `23:59:59.999999` the upper bound, and including it with `]`.